# How to generate typescript from graphQL typeDefs, not by introspection query to running server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

I have many files with type definitions of different queries, like this:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`

// Provide resolver functions for your schema fields
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'Hello world!'
  },
}

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

export default schema
```

I have many such files, which later get combined into one schema.

I want to generate typescript types for every typeDefs.

I found several solutions for types generation from graphql, for example: https://graphql-code-generator.com

But they all work based on the parsing of introspection query result to running API.

I think, it is very clunky for my developing process - having to run types generation, I must run the server before hand, I must also add the required auth headers and this despite the fact that the generation is completely independent of the server, it only depends on typeDefs, which I declared.

Is there any tools, where I can pass typedefs to some function as an argument and generate typescript based on it?